# How can I turn the calendarFormat of Momentjs to the default value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, web, momentjs, single-page-application

I used [Momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) in my SPA application.
My original intention was to use `calendarFormat` to custom my calendar in part of my page and use the default [calendarFormat](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/calendar-format/) in other parts.
Unfortunately I don't know how to set the default calendarFormat.

And ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, you could define a `defaultCalendar` object and use it when you want to show default calendar format:

```js
let defaultCalendar = {
        sameDay: '[Today]',
        nextDay: '[Tomorrow]',
        nextWeek: 'dddd',
        lastDay: '[Yesterday]',
        lastWeek: '[Last] dddd',
        sameElse: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
    };

let anotherCalendar = {
        sameDay: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        nextDay: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        nextWeek: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        lastDay: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        lastWeek: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        sameElse: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
    };

console.log(moment().calendar(null, defaultCalendar));

console.log(moment().calendar(null, anotherCalendar));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with an ingenious solution:

```
const defaultCalendarFormat = moment.calendarFormat;
moment.calendarFormat = myCalendarFormat;
moment.calendarFormat = defaultCalendarFormat;
```